# how to split my traffic on percentage basis?

Tags: proxy, webserver

I need to split my traffic coming on my website on the basis of 60-40 or say 70-30 percent basis like 70 percent should go on to code1 and 30 on code2 and visa versa. How can I do that? Please help me along with the code.

Comment: Are code1 and code2 on the same server?

Comment: Use weighted load balancing

Comment: yes its on the same page even like on index page only

Answer (score 3):

In your entry point make random number generator:

```
// index.php

$rnd = rand(0, 100);

if ($rnd < 70) {
    $app->code1();
} else {
    $app->code2();
}
```

Comment: This won't do. It's random.

Comment: @Daan Yes, it's random, but it will finally add up to preferred percentage.

Comment: @Daan, why can't it be random?

Comment: Not necessarily. If 100 users open up index.php. There is still a chance that traffic will be distributed for example 60/40.

Comment: @Daan That's the nature of random. If I would know how much visits I will get, I would calculate it accurately. Obviously you can calculate how much requests you have already, but that would be too expensive for such task

Comment: I understand randomness, but as I interpret OP's question he's asking for an exact distribution of the traffic.

Comment: @Daan Do you have some algorithm (cheep to implement and execute) to calculate percentage of unknown total value?

Comment: @Justinas Not out the top of my head, and I don't think it's relevant either. Question to OP is, should it be exact or not..

Comment: Im also stuck in a similar situation. Im taking % from admin to distribute traffic on webpages but the only solution that can be found is random number generator and comparison with if conditions. I want a more optimized solution if possible. Im wondering what algorithm does google analytics use in order to split traffic between webpages? If anyone has any idea please share.

Comment: @FahadHussain Well, you can track all requests and just distribute first 7 to `$app->code1()` and rest 3 in `$app->code2()`. Then reset counter. That will definitely be 70%

Comment: @Justinas I cant track requests in real time can I ? Like how would i know in advance how many request would be coming to my website? 
Or are you suggesting to track request for a particular time frame say keep tracking request for 1 minute and then distribute the traffic? This wouldn't be ideal because of the wait time for user.

Comment: @FahadHussain Implement own load balancer - have always running script that would keep count in-memory, and would distribute requests

Answer (score 0):

I'm using NGINX as proxy for my traffic, and then using NGINX as webserver behind on every node I have behind this proxy.

Its required min. 3 servers (1x proxy, 2x webserver) and then you need to work with `pass_proxy` in NGINX and the `upstream`

When you are working with `upstream` in NGINX you can defined a weight eg. 0.5 (50%) or 0.7 (70%)

here is readstuff about it
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/

PS: I have change your tags from `php` to `proxy` + `webserver`.

Comment: sorry but i need to add this on my index page only and cannot change it nginx. i need to split traffic onto two different codes and not onto two different links

Comment: Its make no sens to do in your languages prefefl to your http server. your code its execute when the http server its hitting it, the http server can split the traffic before its execute your server side code.